# system("linux_command") vs. Perl library functions

Tags: linux, perl

In Perl, one can either use a Perl builtin or use system() which calls a shell command to achieve the some goal. The problem is, for me as a Perl beginner, it's sometimes difficult to find the Perl equivalent to a Linux command.
Take this one for example:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u > file3
```

I really want to use only the Perl functions to make my more Perlish, but I can't easily find out how to avoid using system() in this case.

So I wonder, is there any advantage of using Perl Library functions than using the system() call? Which is the better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Often the advantage in using library functions is that you can give meaningful error messages when something goes wrong.

For short-lived scripts or when development resources are at a premium, using system instead can make sense.

Comment: Although I like mpapec 's answer best, this one seemed to be more fitted as the accepted one. But Ed Heal mentioned perl doesn't need to launch a process, and Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil mentioned system commands are more efficient under under some circumstances.

Comment: @duleshi do you know now how to avoid `system()` calls?

Comment: @mpapec I'm confused about your question. Since you have told me a Perl way to avoid system() call for my problem. And I understand your code. What do you mean by asking whether I know how to avoid system() now?

Answer (score 9):

```
local $^I;
local @ARGV = qw(file1 file2);
open my $fh, ">", "file3" or die $!;
my %s;

# print {$fh} (LIST) # or using foreach:
print $fh $_ for
  sort
  grep !$s{$_}++,
  <>;
```

Main advantage is portability and not having system dependencies.

More explicit version,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
local $^I;
local @ARGV = qw(file1 file2);
open my $fh, ">", "file3" or die $!;

for my $line (sort uniq readline()) {
  print $fh $line;
}
```

Comment: While using abbreviations like `command for expression`, `$_` and especially `<>` is certainly considered quite perly by many people, i doubt it really helps someone calling themselves Perl beginner. And to be honest, i would not use it in my scripts either unless i can be certain that never any of my colleagues has to read or change it. It is Perl, if i was going for efficiency, i would have used something else. So why not add the few extra words to keep it readable.

Comment: @DeVadder : I like this solution a lot. The only thing I might do is insert a `sub uniq { my %seen; grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @_ }` to simplify the last line to `print $fh $_ for sort uniq( <> );`. In order to learn Perl, one has to appreciate its richness of syntax. This is a great example of it where `cat` and `sort -u` are nicely tied together.

Comment: @DeVadder Although I'm a beginner, I said in the question that I prefer my code to be more perlish. I bought the famous beginner's book "Learning Perl" and have almost finished reading it. But I practice very rarely so I'm not good at it. But I do want to grasp some advanced features.

Comment: @duleshi: It is just that i am one of those regular Perl users who disagree that code is better or more perly the fewer words or lines it contains. Our testing scripts tend to become quite big and complicated and i prefer them to remain easily readable even for people not used to Perl. That is because often colleagues not using Perl a lot need to modify the script because they need to test something different in the actual software we develop (C++). And it annoys me how Perl has the nimbus of beeing write-only code. Perl allows to write code everyone can read without knowing Perl at all.

Comment: But i digress. :) As always mpapecs solutions of course work and are efficient, so do not take my personal opinion as anything but that.

Comment: @DeVadder I totally agree with you. I see it as an advice from a veteran and a rule any good developer should follow. But don't you think writing something like this is cool? And writing code your boss can't easily understand sometimes make sense. :) So for me, for now, just let me enjoy it when it doesn't cause trouble.

Comment: when you use ARGV like that in modular code, it's a very good idea to also localize `$^I`.  (gotchas like that are one reason I'm on @DeVadder's side)

Comment: @ysth good catch, although `$^I` is mainly used with one liners.

Answer (score 4):

Use perl library. Saves the processor effort in spawning another process. Also able to get better indication when things go wrong.

Comment: Just to confirm. You mean system() launches a new child process while perl library funcs don't, right? I'll be glad if that's true. Or why we bother to go deep into perl since we can system commands instead.

Comment: @duleshi - To avoid the overhead of spawning other processes.

Comment: @duleshi: Yes, system() forks and waits for the child.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a system command and making it perlish i will recommend using open().

```
open(fh,"cat test.txt text_file.txt | sort -u >new_file.txt | ");
```

This makes your program simple and easy to understand.The support provided in perl for system commands is one of the beauties of it.So its better to use it the way it is rather then going the whole trip round just to make your code 'Perlish'.

Comment: But as a simple counterexample, if there are a lot of duplicates, you can save a lot of memory by dropping the duplicates already when reading in the data.

Comment: @tripleee `-u` drops duplicates

Comment: Yes, but `cat` needs to read them all before `sort -u` can drop them, whereas a natural Perl solution would drop a duplicate immediately when reading it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use Perl script version as pointed out by [mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec). But usage of `system` or `open` version pointed by [Asif Idris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705971/asif-idris) have some advantages. For example if you need sort big amount of data, using system command `sort` will bring you much further wit a lot less pain. Sorting few GB using perl is PITA but it is not big deal for system command `sort` and you will even use all your cores and much less memory.

Comment: Could you please explain why the system sort is better when dealing with GB data? Or is it just a rule of thumb? It's obvious the perl funcs' advantage of no need to lanch a new process becomes negligible when doing so heavy job. But why perl is slower?

Comment: The *nix `sort`, specifically, is optimized for sorting files on disk.  If you wish to sort data of a size that rivals or exceeds your RAM, nothing really beats it.  On the flip side, if you go pure perl, writing cross-platform scripts will not require juggling command line parameters and output formats of the BSD/SYS5/GNU versions of your utilities.  Judge that trade-off yourself.